# Why do some emails go into deleted messages folder in iCloud?

Tags: mail.app, icloud

I forward all email from my gmail account to iCloud using POP3 but when I delete emails in iCloud some go to the trash folder, which is where I want them to go, but sometimes a folder called 'deleted messages' is created for the deleted emails.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Are you using Outlook 2011 or any version of Outlook/Entourage to access your email?

Comment: No, just using mac mail.

Comment: This could be "one of those things" when dealing with IMAP. I know that the Trash and Deleted Messages thing is a client setting, and if you're accessing the same iCloud mailbox from different clients, this could be causing the issue.